# Reusable Environmental Variables in helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Currently in my deployment.yaml, I have a list of environment variables that are duplicated across all my services. I wish to move all of them in a common folder. So I have created a common chart with type as library as per the chart.yaml below:

```
annotations:
  category: Infrastructure
  licenses: Apache-2.0
apiVersion: v2
appVersion: 2.4.0
description: A Library Helm Chart for grouping common logic between bitnami charts. This chart is not deployable by itself.
home: https://bitnami.com
icon: https://bitnami.com/downloads/logos/bitnami-mark.png
keywords:
  - common
  - helper
  - template
name: common
type: library
version: 2.4.0
```

Currently the folder structure is as per below where the _helpers.tpl is empty for now:

[image]

Regarding my service, it is as per below:

[image]

Below is part of the deployment.yaml of the service

```
      containers:
    - name: "servicea"
      env:
        - name: role
          value: {{ .Values.role }}
        #What to insert here to get environment variables from common
      ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
```

The service chart.yaml is as follows, trying to refer to the common folder:

```
name: servicea
version: 1.0.0
appVersion: 1.0.0
description: service A
keywords:
  - servicea
apiVersion: v2
dependencies:
  - name: common
    version: 2.4.0
    repository: "file://../../common"
```

What should be written in the _helpers.tpl and how I should refer to the env name/value in the service deployment.yaml?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [define a named template](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/) that generates a fragment of the `env:` block.  If you have a single chart that has multiple Deployments in it, I'd put it in that chart's `_helpers.tpl` file.

```yaml
{{/* servicea/templates/_helpers.tpl */}}
{{- define "servicea.env" -}}
- name: KEY
  value: key value
- name: OTHER
  value: {{ .Values.other }}
{{ end -}}
```

Then when you want to include that, use the [`include`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/#the-include-function) function, combined with `indent` to put it at the right place.  The line including `indent` must not itself be indented.

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
    - name: "servicea"
      env:
        - name: role
          value: {{ .Values.role }}
#^^^^^^^ 8 spaces of indentation here
{{ include "servicea.env" . | indent 8 }}
```

If you need to share this across multiple related Helm charts, the mechanic is exactly the same, except that the `define` needs to go into the library chart; in your layout, in `common/templates/_helpers.tpl`.  You'd call the named template exactly the same way, from any chart that depends on your common chart.

Comment: Hi. can you please have a look at this question I posted? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76348219/helm-template-with-environment-variables. It is related.