# Helm template with environment variables

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a structure as per below whereby common environment variables across `servicea` and `serviceb` are placed in `_helpers.tpl` in the common folder

[image]

Below is the content of `_helpers.tpl` of common

```
{{/* servicea/templates/_helpers.tpl */}}
{{- define "servicea.env" }}
 - name: KEY
   value: {{ .Values.spring.cloud.kubernetes.enabled }}
 - name: OTHER
   value: test
{{ end -}}
```

and its `values.yaml` as per below:

```
spring:
 cloud:
  kubernetes:
   enabled: true
```

for example in `servicea`, if I need to include the common env variables, I will do as per below:

```
containers:
    - name: "servicea"
      env:
        - name: role
          value: role
{{ include "servicea.env" . | indent 12 }}
```

In the `values.yaml` of `servicea`, they are listed as below:

```
servicea: 
  replicaCount: 1
```

and the `dev-values.yaml` as per below:

```
servicea: 
  replicaCount: 2
serviceb: 
  replicaCount: 2
```

Now the issue I am facing is that when I run helm template to generate the manifests, it is giving me the error **Error: template: <.Values.spring.cloud.kubernetes.enabled>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}**.
I can understand that when it is trying to run the template locally, the property spring.cloud.kubernetes.enabled and its value are not present in the values.yaml of servicea as it is only present in the values.yaml of common. If I add the property spring.cloud.kubernetes.enabled in values.yaml of servicea, it works fine. But I do not want as I do not want to repeat the property across all services. Is there a function that "execute the template and then import it after the execution"?
Thank you.

Comment: Is the "inlclude" a typo you made when pasting here? Or is it in your code as well?

Comment: Apologies. Its a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call a named template from an other (dependency) chart, it still runs in the parent chart's context, and sees the *parent's* `.Values`.  There's not a way to "switch into the child" here; you need to provide the defaults in the template code itself.

Mechanically: inside `servicea.env` you call `.Values`, but in this context `.` is the parameter to the template.  When you `include "servicea.env" .`, in that context `.` is the top-level Helm object for the service-A chart, and you're passing that as the parameter.  There's never a point where the definition of `.Values` changes to the common-chart values.

(I'm not even sure it's possible for the parent chart to see the default values in the common chart; I think *e.g.* `.Values.common.spring` will only see what's in the parent chart's `values.yaml` and deploy-time configuration, but not what's in `common/values.yaml`.  You also can't access these files using `.Files`.)

Instead of including this default configuration in the common chart's `values.yaml` you need to include it in code.  Here you need to account for the possibility that none of this configuration will exist at all; if there isn't a `.Values.spring` then you need to provide a `default` empty `dict` instead so lookups at deeper levels continue to work.  I'd probably write this as:

```yaml
{{- define "servicea.env" }}
{{- $spring := .Values.spring | default dict }}
{{- $cloud := $spring.cloud | default dict }}
{{- $kubernetes := $cloud.kubernetes | default dict }}
 - name: KEY
{{- if hasKey $kubernetes "enabled" }}
   value: {{ $kubernetes.enabled | toString | quote }}
{{- else }}
   value: "true"
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

You might consider using a shallower values structure, rather than replicating Spring's configuration here.  If this is setting the Spring environment variable `SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_ENABLED` you might just always force it on, unless you have a specific need to disable it sometimes.

Comment: Since I have multiple env variables, is there a possibiliy to pass everything as key value pairs and then using range to do the looping?

Comment: I've definitely seen a style of Helm chart where large fractions of Kubernetes configuration are passed directly in the values file; you could use `toYaml` to render a list directly into the output.  (I tend to prefer specific settings like `disableSpringCloudKubernetes` or something even higher-level.)

Comment: do you have an example to share or another stackoverflow thread that can be hepful plz?